# Get post Using facebook graph api

Tags: php, facebook

I did one sample to get page post using graph API. But it will fetch all the posts. For example, if the page shares anything from another page, it also fetched from api. I only need the post which is added by that page. Is the feature available in facebook API.

The below URL fetches all the post.
https://graph.facebook.com/page_id/posts?access_token=access_token

Comment: If a page shares a post, that _is_ a post “added by that page”. If you are not interested in certain types of posts made by the page, then you need to filter them on your end.

Answer (score 0):

According to Facebook Docs for [Page Feed](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.8/page/feed)

It clearly states that:

> - /{page-id}/posts shows only the posts that were published by this    page.
> - /{page-id}/tagged shows all public posts in which the page has    been tagged.
> - /{page-id}/promotable_posts shows only the posts that    can be boosted (includes unpublished and scheduled posts).

Please check the docs properly and if you want to customize it more then you can do that at your end while parsing the results.